# Run method without binding it to event click event SignalR

Tags: jquery, signalr-hub

As stated in the official SignalR sample:

```
 $(function () {
                 var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
                 chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (x) {
                    console.log(x)
                 };

                 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#button1').click(function(){
                chat.server.send(x);
                        });

                 });

             });
```

it works perfect  but, my question would be how to run the `send` method from outside,without binding it to click an so ,this code is actually works for me, but I don't think it is practical:

```
              var chat;
               $(function () {
                 chat = $.connection.chatHub;
                 chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (x) {
                    console.log(x)
                 };

                 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                });

             });


              var outsidefunction = function(){
                  chat.server.send(x);
             }



            //////lets say
              $ajax(
                 success:function(){
                     outsidefunction();
                   }
              )
```

if you noticed 
my code:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    });
```

stays empty inside, and if i put it outside the `ready` function it doesn't work

thanks

Comment: Faced with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use like

```
function outsidefunction(x) {
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    chat.server.send(x);

});
}
```

Then you can call `outsidefunction(x)` whenever you want

Comment: so do you think it is practical

Comment: sorry dude, I didn't refresh the page and I thought it was working, but it actually not. have to unanswer to get other feedbacks.it works only for one client hub, when i trigger it form other client it doesn't triggger

Comment: so do you have other client hubs?

Comment: yes am testing on 3 browsers, and only firefox triggers with your method, and it actually works for all with what I specified

Comment: My assumption is that, the connection will establish to server only after sending the first message. Can yoi try send message from each browser. Only one message is enough. Then mu solution will work